# Is there a way to make custom shapes in html?

Tags: html, css

I've done some research and haven't found if it is possible to do irregular shapes with html.
The kind of shapes i'm referring is like the ones we see below:

[image: shape1]

[image: shape2]

From what I know, we can easily implement this in Html using images.

We can, for example, use an image at 100% of width, but that means it will probably be too stretched or the opposite.

If I use a lot of images for different resolutions it will be better but the web page will be heavy.

That's the main reason for my question,  is there a way to do something like this with html and css or the only solution is using `.svg` files that is not an html solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far that did not work ? pseudos and radius, clip-path, gradient, SVG, .. ?

Comment: It should be noted that the only HTML part of this (off topic and should be closed) question is the `<svg>` element. All the rest is under a completely different specification and standard and, in fact, is actually XML.

Comment: @Rob what do you mean? The answer or the question of this topic?

Comment: Both. SVG is not HTML

Comment: @Rob i edited my question. Svg is not html, but it's code can be included on the web page html and the different parts of it can be manipulated with css and javascript i've already, that's i've considered it.

Answer (score 0):

For shapes directly in HTML, I would suggest using the SVG tag similar to:

```html
<svg height="130" width="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="86">SVG</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

The above snip was found on: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp

Comment: Hello @Xex svg might be a good solution, I'm still learning how to create and use them. Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that the only HTML part of the (off topic and should be closed) question is the `<svg>` element. All the rest is under a completely different specification and standard and, in fact, is actually XML.